# AlamofireImage Placeholder image briefly shown before cached image v3.1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have table view that presents a list of images. I feel like my tableview is as simple as it gets, however I cannot get af_setImage to work correctly.

When I scroll up and down the table I am again presented with the placeholderImage for a second or so before the correct image appears.

**For example** when the tableview first appears I can see three images in the list. If I scroll to the bottom of the table and back up to the top, I am presented again with the placeholderImage for a second or so.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

    let url = URL(string: self.dataReponseArray[indexPath.row].imageDownloadUrl)!
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "bike")!

    cell.customCellImage.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

I swapped af_setImage with sd_setImage from SDWebImage and now its working as expected.

```
cell.customCellImage.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

with

```
cell.customCellImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://pathToMyIMage"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: every time you scroll down and scroll up again the cell is set again. So image is redownloaded and then presented on that cell. so its taking time.
fir download all images and then only use set image property

Comment: You can check it out this library for loading image 
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: @iOSDev that is the library I am using.

Comment: @Rooney I know that cells are reused, however according to the AlamofireImage documentation, af_setImage will first check the cache to see if that image was previously downloaded. If it exists in the cache it will not show the placeholderImage and imediately show the cached image.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you don't use `placeholderImage`.

I have a similar project. Firstly i set placeholder image manually.

```
cell.customCellImage.image = placeholderImage
```

Then
`af_setImage(withURL: url)`

Default image (placeholder image) shows only once.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

    let url = URL(string: self.dataReponseArray[indexPath.row].imageDownloadUrl)!
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "bike")!

    cell.customCellImage.image = placeholderImage
    cell.customCellImage.af_setImage(withURL: url)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post. Unfortunately that did not work. It actually produces the same result.